# Run Selenium Script on browser stack

Tags: java, selenium, browserstack

I am trying to run my selenium script on Browser stack , while running script facing problem while switching to frame. sometime it does but sometime not.
Is there any permanent solution for it.

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
List iframeElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")); 
System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size()); 
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frame); Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Please add the code you tried for switching to the frame and the html snippet of the frame.The permanent solution could be to wait for the frame to be available and after to switch to it, on BS the execution is slightly slower.

Comment: driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  List<WebElement> iframeElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
  System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size());
  
  WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
  driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
  Thread.sleep(5000);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Answer (score 0):

You can wait until frame to be available as given below. It may help you.

```
WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 90);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frame));
```